# Одинаковые имена полей двух разных Form

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

На одной странице, но в разных вкладках есть одинаковые формы и делающие одно и тоже. Сделать одну форму не представляется возможности должно быть именно две. 
Не будет ли проблемы, если есть две одинаковые формы на одной странице и с одинаковыми именами полей.
Возможно есть другой способ все это провернуть?

Comment: А вот вопрос, а если формам не присваивать имя и id, несколько форм будут содержать одинаковые имена полей(input), не будет ли потом загвостки при отправке запроса?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Имена полей в разных формах могут совпадать.

Главное, чтобы все id элементов (если вы их прописываете) и имена форм на странице были уникальными и не повторялись.

Answer (score 1):

Проблемы не будет, главное чтобы сами формы имели разные ID.

Comment: формы имеют разный ID. А если поля в формах будут иметь одинаковые ID?

Comment: Одинаковые name - пожалуйста, но не ID. Суть id в уникальности.

Comment: @Raaur, если одновременно на странице присутствует (именно присутствует, а не видима) только одна из форм, то можно. Но id должны быть уникальны в рамках страницы в любой момент времени.

Answer (score -1):

А вот у меня с одиннаковымми `name` была проблема.
Приходили пустые значения в php:

```
$email = trim($_POST["email"]);
```

Т.к. в одной форме я заполняю, а в другой то поле пустое...

Обрабатывал так:

```
$("form#one").submit()...
$("form#other").submit()...
```

Comment: Павел, то, что Вы описываете не может происходить так, как Вы это описываете.

Comment: сам понимаю, что не должно, но как только заменил name - ситуация исправилась